# Why is my Scrapy scraper only returning the second page of results?

Tags: python, regex, screen-scraping, scrapy

College is starting soon for me, so I decided to build a web scraper for Rate My Professor to help me find the highest rated teachers at my school. The scraper works perfectly well... but only for the second page! No matter what I try, I can't get it to work properly.

This is the URL that I am scraping from: http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?sid=2311&pageNo=3  (not my actual college, but has the same type of URL structure)

And here is my spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from rmp.items import RmpItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "rmp"
    allowed_domains = ["ratemyprofessors.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?sid=2311"]

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('&pageNo=\d',), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="next"]',)), callback='parser', follow=True),)

    def parser(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        html = hxs.select("//div[@class='entry odd vertical-center'] | // div[@class='entry even vertical-center']")
        profs = []
        for line in html:
            prof = RmpItem()
            prof["name"] = line.select("div[@class='profName']/a/text()").extract()
            prof["dept"] = line.select("div[@class='profDept']/text()").extract()
            prof["ratings"] = line.select("div[@class='profRatings']/      text()").extract()
            prof["avg"] = line.select("div[@class='profAvg']/text()").extract()
            profs.append(prof)
```

Some things I have tried include removing the restrict_xpaths keyword argument (resulted in the scraper going after the first, the last, the next, and the back buttons because all share the &pageNo=\d URL structure) and changing the regex of the allow keyword argument (resulted in no change).

Does anybody have any suggestions? This seems to be a simple problem, but I've already spent an hour and a half trying to figure it out! Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: There is no return statement in `parser()`, see 
[Spiders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spiders) point #2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site does not handle very well the page argument when is not in the expected order.
See the `href` value:

```
$ curl -q -s  "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?sid=2311&pageNo=2"  |grep \"next\"
    <a href="/SelectTeacher.jsp?sid=2311&pageNo=3" id="next">c</a>
$ curl -q -s  "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?pageNo=2&sid=2311"  |grep \"next\"
    <a href="/SelectTeacher.jsp?pageNo=2&sid=2311&pageNo=3" id="next">c</a>
```

To avoid modifying the original url you should use the parameter `canonicalize=False` for the `SgmlLinkExtractor` class. Also you might want to use a less specific xpath rule because with your current rule you don't get the items for the start url.

Like this:

```
rules = [
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@id="pagination"]', 
                           canonicalize=False),
         callback='parser', follow=True),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted on the Scrapy Google Groups page and received an answer! Here it is:

I think you may have found a bug

When I fetch the 1st page in scrapy shell, SgmlLinkExtractor has an issue after the 2nd page

(py2.7)paul@wheezy:~/tmp/rmp$ scrapy shell http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?sid=2311
...

> > > from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
> > >       SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="next"]',)).extract_links(response)
> > >       [Link(url='http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?pageNo=2&sid=2311', text=u'c', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
> > >
> > > fetch('http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?pageNo=2&sid=2311')
> > >       2013-09-19 02:05:38+0200 [rmpspider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?pageNo=2&sid=2311> (referer: None)
> > >       ...
> > >       SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="next"]',)).extract_links(response)
> > >       [Link(url='http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?pageNo=2&pageNo=3&sid=2311', text=u'c', fragment='', nofollow=False)]

But when I run the shell starting from the 2nd page directly, it's ok for the next page,
but the next link from the 3rd page is wrong again

(py2.7)paul@wheezy:~/tmp/rmp$ scrapy shell "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?sid=2311&pageNo=2"
...

> > > from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
> > >       SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="next"]',)).extract_links(response)
> > >       [Link(url='http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?pageNo=3&sid=2311', text=u'c', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
> > >
> > > fetch('http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?pageNo=3&sid=2311')
> > >       ...
> > >       SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="next"]',)).extract_links(response)
> > >       [Link(url='http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?pageNo=3&pageNo=4&sid=2311', text=u'c', fragment='', nofollow=False)]

In the meantime,
you can write an equivalent spider using BaseSpider and constructing the next page request "by hand", with a little HtmlXPathSelector select() and urlparse.urljoin()

```
#from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
#from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from rmp.items import RmpItem
import urlparse

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "rmpspider"
    allowed_domains = ["ratemyprofessors.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?sid=2311"]

    #rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="next"]',)), callback='parser', follow=True),)

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        html = hxs.select("//div[@class='entry odd vertical-center'] | // div[@class='entry even vertical-center']")
        for line in html:
            prof = RmpItem()
            prof["name"] = line.select("div[@class='profName']/a/text()").extract()
            yield prof

        for url in hxs.select('//a[@id="next"]/@href').extract():
            yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url))
```